# Iterate over an array of Objects and get the key Angular 2

Tags: angular

Hi I have a data structure as below:

```
list = [{id: "test", name: "name1"}, {id: "test1", name: "name2"}, ..]
```

I want to display the keys (id and name) as th in my table. Since i didnt find any buitin pipes i created a custom one.

```
@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
    }
    return keys;
  }
}
```

But in my html, am getting only 0, 1 , 2, ... as keys. Any idea whats happening wrong here?

Comment: What does your template look like?

Comment: What do you really want to display? You have an array of objects, why not iterate it as is? `<div *ngFor="let item of list">{{item.id}} {{item.name}}</div>` Maybe I'm misunderstanding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this would help:

```
@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    let keys = [];
    Object.keys(value).forEach(function(key){
      keys.push({key: key, value: value['value']});
    }); 

    return keys;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this, I didn't tried but it should work. The problem is that u are iterating over the array, not over the object. And then, where u say "key" it is the **index** of the array so, that's why u are getting, "0, 1, 2".
Is your table like this?:

```
ID    NAME
id1   name1
id2   name2
...   ...
```

Comment: Not what am expecting Alberto.

Comment: have the keys dynamic length (ej: id, name, age, etc)?